# Accessing variables outside a React promise in PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, promise, discord

I have code similar to the following that uses DiscordPHP to send pre-populated messages to certain users in my server.

The code works fine till the foreach loop and the `$message` variable contains my messages within. However, the function within the promise (`$discord->users->fetch($discordid, false)->done()`) looses the `$message` value and using `global` doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how can I reference a variable set outside the promise?

```
$messages = [];
$messages['123'] = [ "Hello", "World" ];

if (count($messages) > 0) {
    $discord = new Discord([
        'token' => '<discord token>',
    ]);

    $discord->on('ready', function ($discord) {
        global $messages;

        foreach ($messages as $discordid=>$message) {
            $user = $discord->users->fetch($discordid, false)
                    ->done(
                        function($user){
                            global $message;

                            $ret = $user->sendMessage("This is a sample message.\n".implode("\n", $message));
                        }
                    );
        }
    });

    $discord->run();
}
```

Comment: I've never done this with a promise, but have you tried the `use` option?
`function($user) use($messages) { }`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.